# Why was my answer with a +1 score deleted by a ♦ moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728828/3956566) to [Is there a script to bypass 50000 characters for in-cell formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54727816/1595451) was deleted by a ♦ moderator without any explanation of the reason. My answer has +2 / -1.

- Why it was deleted?
- Why there isn't a comment describing the problem pointing what was wrong?

Here is the content of my answer at the time that it was deleted (rev 1):

---

> Is there a script to bypass 50000 characters for in-cell formula?

If the length of `{B!A1:A100; ........ ; CA!DZ1:DZ100}` is greater than 50 thousands characters consider to build a custom function that build the array for you. You could "hard-code" the references or list them as text on a range to be read by your script.

Then, the resulting formula could look like this `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(MYCUSTOMFUNCTION(), 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))` or like this `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(MYCUSTOMFUNCTION(A1:A1000), 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))` (assuming that you have 1000 references.

Comment: It looks like the mod handled the Low Quality Review caused by a flag on the post:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TIN3.png

Comment: Yeh it's the early morning for this mod - I undeleted it and Sam can explain why he deleted it.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you. In the mid time I extended the original answer because another question was marked as a possible duplicate. Not sure if that solved the "low-quality" problem.

Comment: @Rubén I'm not sure why it was deleted. I saw the post flagged and left it for the low qual queue to sort out. I didn't think it was low qual or not an answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have reviewed the post again and have determined it was deleted incorrectly.

Mods see a short excerpt of the post in the flag queue, *without line-breaks and formatting*. From what I saw it could have been a comment instead as it started with a question. The error I made was not expanding the complete answer (which would have shown the second paragraph) before making a decision then.

Please accept my sincerest apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Apologies accepted and thank you for the explanation. The question in the answer was a quote taken from the question. Next time that I add a quote will start with something else.

Comment: Have you considered a temporary break from reviewing the mod queue? Sort of like the review suspensions that are given to regular users who mess up?

Comment: Hey @RobertColumbia that comment is a bit out of character as it reads to me as a snark towards the user. That is not how I remember your regular comments. Is that just me or was that your intent in this single case?

Comment: No offense taken. Anyway this was a month ago and I have taken a long break since then...